# getting values from column in database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-cursor

I am getting values from the column "threadid" in the database.Problem is that it gets the value from the previous record/row. and when I try to get the first record my app crashes,, How to tackle this problem and whats the issue?

```
long id;
long threadid = datasource.getthreadid(id);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(threadid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

public long getthreadid(long id)
  {

      String ide=String.valueOf(id);
      String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID 
                + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME 
                + " WHERE " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + ide;
      Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryz, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
     // cursor.moveToPosition(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));
     long threadid= cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("threadid"));

      cursor.close();
    return threadid;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only expecting one row. Then it might be useful to do something like this.

```
long threadid;

if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    threadid = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("threadid"));
}
else
{
    // ah oh, we do not have this id!
    // do something here if you need to
}
```

Also, if you are going to use strings, I recommend you bind the parameters. I know you had a long beforehand, but for strings you can do this.

```
  String queryz = "SELECT " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID 
            + " FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME 
            + " WHERE " + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
  Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(queryz, new String[]{ide});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the records, you first need to move to the first one, then you iterate through the rest.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // get row values
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

cursor.close();
```